# Creating and Populating an external Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I come from a C#/Java background and I'm trying to go about learning how to make games in HTML5. I ran across a problem that has been boggling my mind, and although normally I would ask a friend, he's been MIA. I feel bad having created an account to ask the community, but I've been searching for the answer to no avail.

So the problem is this...
I want to create a gameobject that can hold an instance of a tower. Also, I want to create an array list of towers as a sort of back-end repository. Essentially, I was hoping these would be external js files that I would be able to reference in my main game. I'm not sure if this is possible in js or how this would work.

What I attempted to do was...
Create an external JS file and declare a tower object. This is where I got lost. I wanted to make another object that was simply a list of the first type, a towerList. In this external JS file, I was going to populate the list with a bunch of tower properties. Then, in the main file with the canvas element, I was going to iterate through the list and draw out the graphics. I have no idea how to go about this.

```
function Tower (type, texture, cost, damage, speed, range, health, Xpos, Ypos) 
{
this.type = type;
this.texture = new Image();
this.texture.src = texture;
this.cost = 0;
this.damage = 0;
this.speed = 0;
this.range = 0;
this.health = 0;
this.Xposition = 0;
this.Yposition = 0;
this.target = false;
}


var TowerList = [Tower("Basic", "tower.png", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Tower(), Tower()];
```

I doubt I have this working correctly, but I want to be able to create instances of the towerlist in the main project, access it randomly like an array, and print its contents as I see fit. What's the best OO way to accomplish this in JS? I want to be able to later in the main code be able to assign a tower from the list as such

```
var tL = new TowerList();
var tower = new Tower();

tower = tL[0];
```

I just started this today, so I realize there's a lot of learning to be had. I think I need to redefine the function as a var else I can instantiate it (I'm sure I read that earlier). If anyone can help me out or point me in the direction to a resource that has examples that I might be able to learn from, I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`TowerList` doesn't have to be a new type of object, just an `Array` will do:

```
var towerList = [];
towerList.push(new Tower("Basic", "tower.png", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
//             ^^^
//            use 'new' to instantiate a new Tower
towerList.push(...);
```

To iterate over `TowerList`:

```
var tower;

for (var i = 0, n = towerList.length; i < n; ++i) {
    tower = towerList[i];
    // do stuff with tower
}
```

You can make `TowerList` inherit from `Array` as well:

```
function TowerList()
{
}

TowerList.prototype = [];

TowerList.prototype.yourFunction = function() {
}

var towerList = new TowerList();

towerList.push(new Tower(...));

towerList.yourFunction();
```

Comment: he wants to be able to create instances of TowerList.  That may just be a way of saying "having multiple arrays", but if taken literally then it means he wants a class/object type that he may eventually extend with more methods/properties.

Comment: @ben336 The List suffix has a meaning and `Array` comes closest to that.

Comment: fair enough.  I basically suggested the same thing, just with a class wrapper around the array.  If he doesn't intend to expand, your answer is definitely the right one.  Upvoted

Comment: @ben336 If OP wishes to expand it, the more appropriate route might be to use `[]` as the object's prototype so you inherit all the Array goodness :)

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying my original question. I was intending to modify the tower class with methods unless there was a better options, engineering wise or other. I guess I should perhaps take the time to examine the project from an overhead standpoint.

Comment: @user2255691 I've added an example of how could inherit from Array.

Comment: I appreciate it Jack. I think I'm going to take some time to read a book on the subject that way I can make a more informed question.

Answer (score 0):

```
//your towers should be called using new here, assuming you actually 
//want a list of towers
var TowerList = [Tower("Basic", "tower.png", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Tower(), Tower()];
//TowerList needs to be a function to be called with new.  This will error out.
var tL = new TowerList();
//This should work correctly
var tower = new Tower();

//this would overwrite the new Tower() with tl[0]
tower = tL[0];
```

If you want to be able to create TowerList objects you probably want something like this

```
function TowerList(){
    this.list = [];

}


TowerList.prototype.addTower(tower){
  list.push(tower);

}


TowerList.prototype.getList(){
  return this.list;

}
```

Then you can just do this

```
var tL = new TowerList();
tL.addTower(new Tower("Basic", "tower.png", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
tL.addTower(new Tower());


var tower = tL[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for offering your insights. You gave me some good ideas for code reminiscent of what I was used to.

Comment: No problem. If any of these answers were helpful you should upvote them, and if they solved your problem you should accept them.  That's generally how people say thank you on this site :)

Answer (score 0):

I would probably have tower return an object and then create instances of that. (avoiding "this")

Consider a modular approach: This helped me: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Rough Idea:

```
function Tower(type, texture, cost, damage, speed, range, health, Xpos, Ypos)  {
    var obj = {};
        obj.type = type;
        obj.texture = new Image();
        obj.texture.src = texture;
        obj.cost = cost;
        obj.damage = 0;
        obj.speed = 0;
        obj.range = 0;
        obj.health = 0;
        obj.Xposition = 0;
        obj.Yposition = 0;
        obj.target = false;

    return obj;
}


var TowerList = [Tower("Basic", "r", 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Tower(), Tower()];
var mytower = TowerList[1];
```

Comment: I appreciate the link. I am reviewing the modular pattern to see how it would resolve my issue.